# R: Apply function on each row with specific columns in loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, statistical-test

I created a loop to perform a statistical test on my dataset. The 2 samples I compare are certain columns of the same data frame. So I want to perform the test to each row and just save the p-value as a new column of the data frame.
When performing I get the same p-value for each row. Could someone tell me where my mistake is?
Thank you!

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) { df$P_Value <- t.test(df[i,c(2:4)], df[i,c(5:7)], var.equal = FALSE)$p.value}
```

this is what I tried

Comment: You need to assign your result to the `i`th row: `df$P_Value[i] <- t.test(...`